# UIViewController won't change orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

**ViewController**

1.

*shouldAutorotate* method is called only once.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    NSLog(@"A");

    return YES;
}
```

2.

*viewWillTransitionToSize* method never gets called.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    NSLog(@"B");

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

**Device**

Portrait Orientation Lock: OFF

**Deployment Info**

All device orientations are supported.

**Info.plist**

Same.

-

Besides every being set accordingly the ViewController won't rotate.

The only thing left is the Main.storyboard file where I can't find anything related to orientation changes.

Comment: Its working fine for me. Please try to run this project http://www.filedropper.com/bbb_2

Comment: It's working fine for me too... !